# Do functions satisfying the following conditions generate primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

### What I'm trying to to find

I'm trying to find two functions $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ and $g:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$, such that there are only finitely many $n\in\Bbb{N}$, for which the following condtitions don't hold:
$$|f(n)|<n^2$$
$$f(n)\neq n $$
$$1<g(n)\leq n$$
$$\forall m\in\Bbb{N}: n\mid f(m)\implies g(n)\mid m$$

### Why I'm trying to find those two functions

Take all the primes for which the first two conditions doesn't hold and put them in a set $S$. Take numbers for which the last two conditions don't hold and put them in a set $T$. Now:
$$\forall p\in\Bbb{P}/T\forall q\in\Bbb{P}/S:p\mid f(q)\implies g(p)\mid q\implies g(p)= q \implies p\geq q$$
So all prime factors of $f(q)$ which are not in $T$ are greater than or equal to $q$, but since $f(q)<q^2$, for all $q\in\Bbb{P}/S$ it can only have one prime factor that is not in $T$. So now we have proven:
$$\forall p\in\Bbb{P}:(\not\exists q\in S:q\mid f(p))\implies f(p)\in\Bbb{P}$$
Since $f(x)\neq x$ for all number not in $S$, you can generate primes with it (except when all values of $f$ are divisible by some value in $T$, but I'm looking for a less trivial solution)

### Two functions that come very close

Two functions that come very close are $f(n)=2^n-1$ and $g(n)=\lambda(n)$, where $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael function. We have:
$$\forall n,m\in\Bbb{N}:n>m\implies 2^n-1>2^m-1$$
$$1<\lambda(n)< n$$
$$\forall n\in\Bbb{N}/\{1,2\}\forall m\in\Bbb{N}:n\mid2^m-1\implies \lambda(n)\mid m$$
So in this case $S=\{1,2\}$. The above three properties make that all prime factors of $2^n-1$ are greater than $n$, but since $2^n-1>n^2$ for infinitely many values (in fact for all integer $n>2$), we can't use this function to generate primes.

### Questions

1) First and foremost, do you know two such functions? (if possible not too hard to compute)

2) Also very important, is my proof correct?

3) If you can't find two functions that satisfy all conditions: Can you prove/disprove the existance of two such functions?

If you feel like the title isn't accurate enough, feel free to change it.

### Some things I already know that $f$ and $g$ can't be

1) It cannot be true that $\exists a,b\in\Bbb{Z}:f(x)=ax+b$. Proof: this would mean that if $p\mid f(x_0)$ that then $p\mid f(x_0+p)$ and hence that $g(p)\mid \gcd(ax_0+b,ax_0+ap+b)=a\cdot p$. If we now choose $p$ such that $a\not\equiv 0 \pmod p \wedge a+b\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, then $g(p)=p$ and thus $p\mid b$. But since we can find infitely many primes $p$ which satisfy $a\not\equiv 0 \pmod p \wedge a+b\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, $b$ is infinitely large, so we know for sure that $f(x)\not< x^2$.

2) It cannot be true that $\exists \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{N}:f(n)=\alpha^n-\beta$, Even though we could define $g(x)$ to be function which looks a lot like the Carmichael function and satisfies all conditions except one. If we assume:
$$\alpha^n-\beta<n^2$$ 
then:
$$\log_2(\alpha^n)+\log_2(1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha^n})<2\implies$$
$$n\cdot\log_2\alpha<2$$
$$n<\dfrac{2}{\log_2\alpha}$$
Which clearly isn't true for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

After these two proofs and thinking about the problem for a while, I think the hard thing will be to satisfy both:
$$\forall n\in\Bbb{N}:f(n)<n^2$$
and:
$$\forall n\in\Bbb{N}/S \forall m\in\Bbb{N}: n\mid f(m)\implies g(n)\mid m$$

Comment: the conditions for $f(n)$ are for $\Bbb N$ or for $\Bbb N^+$? in your example $f(n)=2^n-1$ if $n=0$ is $f(0)=2^0-1=1-1=0 \not \lt 0^2 = 0$. I suppose that the condition is then for positive integers according to your example, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't mean $0$. I always thought that $0$ wasn't a natural number, which is why I wrote $\Bbb{N}.

Comment: I've changed the conditions slightly, so that $f(x)=x$ is not longer a trivial example and there can be finitely many exceptions to all conditions.